# How to ping a bounty poster

Tags: discussion, bounty

Here I mean by Investor a person who starts a bounty for somebody else's question.

How can I discuss with an investor? does he receive comments?

Comment: You should look this post on meta stackexchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537

Comment: @RomainPicot, thank you. As one can see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020 Investor is not one of `Who can be notified with this feature?` It would be good idea if he is.

Comment: Related: [How to invite someone to chat?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3591/5764)

Comment: @Oxinabox done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can notify a user who set a bounty on the question by leaving a comment with @TheirName under the question. Although the name does not autocomplete, the ping reaches the user. This works even if the bounty has long expired.

I verified this experimentally, [with the help of tchrist and rene](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3949721#3949721), and updated the [reference post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) accordingly.

And then I found  [an older post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129236) confirming this. It seems that everyone listed in the revision history of a post can be pinged, except for close/reopen voters without a binding vote (i.e., non-mods and non-gold-badge-holders).

Comment: I'll test this as sone as possible. Does anyone think that I should accept this answer?

Comment: @touhami It's totally up to you. But I can't imagine what would stop you from doing so.